# How to add/mutate a Map object in MutableAggregationBuffer in UDAF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.0.1 and Scala 2.11.

This is a question related to user-defined aggregate function (UDAF) in Spark. I'm using the example answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33949693/8098748) to ask my question:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, Column}

object DummyUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def inputSchema = new StructType().add("x", StringType)
  def bufferSchema = new StructType()
    .add("buff", ArrayType(LongType))
    .add("buff2", ArrayType(DoubleType))
  def dataType = new StructType()
    .add("xs", ArrayType(LongType))
    .add("ys", ArrayType(DoubleType))
  def deterministic = true 
  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {}
  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {}
  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {}
  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = (Array(1L, 2L, 3L), Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
}
```

I'm able to return multiple `Map`s instead of an `Array` easily, but not able to mutate the map in the `update` method.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, Column}

import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object DummyUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def inputSchema = new StructType().add("x", DoubleType).add("y", IntegerType)
  def bufferSchema = new StructType()
    .add("buff", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))
    .add("buff2", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))

  def dataType = new StructType()
    .add("xs", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))
    .add("ys", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))

  def deterministic = true 

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer(0) = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Double,Int]()
    buffer(1) = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Double,Int]()
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]](input.getDouble(0)) = input.getInt(1)
    buffer(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]](input.getDouble(0)*10) = input.getInt(1)*10
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    buffer1(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]] ++= buffer2(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]]
    buffer1(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]] ++= buffer2(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]]
  }

  //def evaluate(buffer: Row) = (Map(1.0->10,2.0->20), Map(10.0->100,11.0->110))
  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = (buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]], buffer(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]])
}
```

This compiles fine, but gives a runtime error:

```scala
val df = Seq((1.0, 1), (2.0, 2)).toDF("k", "v")
df.select(DummyUDAF($"k", $"v")).show(1, false)

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 70.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 70.0 (TID 204, 10.91.252.25): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$ cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

Another solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36630305/8098748) indicates that this could be a problem due to `MapType StructType`. However, when I try out the solution mentioned I still get the same error.

```scala
val distudaf = new DistinctValues
val df = Seq(("a", "a1"), ("a", "a1"), ("a", "a2"), ("b", "b1"), ("b", "b2"), ("b", "b3"), ("b", "b1"), ("b", "b1")).toDF("col1", "col2")

df.groupBy("col1").agg(distudaf($"col2").as("DV")).show

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 22.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 22.0 (TID 100, 10.91.252.25): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$ cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

My preference would be to mutate the Map, given that I expect the Map to be huge, and making a copy and re-assigning may be lead to performance/memory bottlenecks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My limited understanding of UDAF is that you should only **set** what you want to be (semantically) updated, i.e. take what is set already in `MutableAggregationBuffer`, combine with what you want to add and...`=` it (which will call `update(i: Int, value: Any): Unit` under the covers)

Your code could look as follows:

```
def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
  val newBuffer0 = buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double, Int]]
  buffer(0) = newBuffer0 + (input.getDouble(0) -> input.getInt(1))

  val newBuffer1 = buffer(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double, Int]]
  buffer(1) = newBuffer1 + (input.getDouble(0) * 10 -> input.getInt(1) * 10)
}
```

The complete `DummyUDAF` could be as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, Column}

object DummyUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def inputSchema = new StructType().add("x", DoubleType).add("y", IntegerType)
  def bufferSchema = new StructType()
    .add("buff", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))
    .add("buff2", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))

  def dataType = new StructType()
    .add("xs", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))
    .add("ys", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))

  def deterministic = true 

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer(0) = Map[Double,Int]()
    buffer(1) = Map[Double,Int]()
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val newBuffer0 = buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double, Int]]
    buffer(0) = newBuffer0 + (input.getDouble(0) -> input.getInt(1))

    val newBuffer1 = buffer(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double, Int]]
    buffer(1) = newBuffer1 + (input.getDouble(0) * 10 -> input.getInt(1) * 10)
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    buffer1(0) = buffer1(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]] ++ buffer2(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]]
    buffer1(1) = buffer1(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]] ++ buffer2(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]]
  }

  //def evaluate(buffer: Row) = (Map(1.0->10,2.0->20), Map(10.0->100,11.0->110))
  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = (buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]], buffer(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Double,Int]])
}
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this copies data twice on each call of `update` so doesn't really address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Late for the party. I just discovered that one can use

```
override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(List(
    StructField("map", ObjectType(classOf[mutable.Map[String, Long]]))
))
```

to use `mutable.Map` in a buffer.

Comment: Can you please post a full example? I did `import scala.collection.mutable` and tried your solution. However, got an error at *runtime*: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unsupported data type ObjectType(interface scala.collection.mutable.Map)`